# MDB not listening after startup

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean

I have a Message Producer running on one JVM that puts in messages in a JMS Queue .I have a Message Consumer which implements Message-Driven-Bean and MessageListener interface that listens to this queue.This Message consumer is on a different JVM.

The producer puts in messages in the queue properly.But the MDB is not able to pop out messages from queue.The weird thing is that when I restart my Message Consumer , all the messages in the queue are popped out by the Message Consumer at once.After this,no matter how many messages producer puts in the queue ,the Message Consumer does not pop them out.
What could be the reason??

The application server I am using is JBOSS4.0.5.GA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details. From what you have provided:

- is your consumer running and waiting for messages ? (inside some sort of while loop or a blocking call)
- you can set `prefetch` size for your consumer to be 1 in your jms connection settings so that it fetches only 1 (or whatever number) message from the queue.

Comment: The consumer is running.There are already messages in the queue.It is expected to pop those messages out and start processing them.But it isnt.I have to restart it.No there isnt any kind of loop.Its an implementation of MDB and has an onMessage() method.

Comment: okay, so if your consumer in not constantly listening to the messages, it will get messages only once. what you need is a thread that keeps on listening to the queue.

Comment: I guess thats what an MDB is supposed to do, right?It is supposed to keep on listening to the queue.Please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: yes. thats why unless i someone sees your code as to what you have done, its difficult to help.